# how to update bound of PositionConstraint?

Tags: drake

We want speed up the IK solve porocess, so we want to update the bound of IK constraints, instead of creating constraints every time solve IK problems.

We noticed that there are APIs like `set_bounds()` to update bounds in `BoundingBoxConstraint`, `LinearConstraint`, etc. But the bound of `PositionConstraint` cann't be  updated this way.

Is this discouraged, or there are some way to update bounds of `PositionConstraint`?

Thanks!

Comment: That was a mistake when I created PositionConstraint, I will add the function such that it can update the bounds. Thanks for reporting this.

Comment: The PR https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/16631 was just merged into Drake. Now you can use seg_bounds, UpdateLowerBound and UpdateUpperBound in PositionConstraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PR #16631 was just merged into Drake. Now you can use set_bounds, UpdateLowerBound and UpdateUpperBound in PositionConstraint.

[PositionConstraint.set_bounds documentation](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.multibody.inverse_kinematics.html#pydrake.multibody.inverse_kinematics.PositionConstraint.set_bounds)

```py
        constraint = ik.PositionConstraint(
            plant=variables.plant,
            frameA=variables.body1_frame,
            p_AQ_lower=[-0.1, -0.2, -0.3],
            p_AQ_upper=[-0.05, -0.12, -0.28],
            frameB=variables.body2_frame,
            p_BQ=[0.2, 0.3, 0.5], plant_context=variables.plant_context)
        constraint.UpdateLowerBound(new_lb=np.array([-2, -3, -0.5]))
        constraint.UpdateUpperBound(new_ub=np.array([10., 0.5, 2.]))
        constraint.set_bounds(new_lb=[-1, -2, -2.], new_ub=[1., 2., 3.])
```