# Is it possible to update the bounds of `Constraint`?

Tags: drake

I'm using `KinematicTrajecotyOptimization`. I want to update the coefficients for some constraints and then resolve the problem. Some of the constraints can be updated because they are `LinearConstraint`, but others can't be updated because they are `Constraint` which does not have API like `UpdateCoefficients`. For example the constraints 1 and 2 in the following code:

```
trajopt = KinematicTrajectoryOptimization(...)
goal_constraint = PositionConstraint(...)
trajopt.AddPathPositionConstraint(goal_constraint, 1)  # constraint 1
dq_constraint = LinearConstraint(...)
trajopt.AddVelocityConstraintAtNormalizedTime(dq_constraint, 0)  # constraint 2
```

It seems updating coefficients of `goal_constraint` is not effective.

Comment: If I'm reading correctly, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71157985/how-to-update-bound-of-positionconstraint.

Comment: I think it's a different issue since after adding `PositionConstraint` to `trajopt` using `AddPathPositionConstraint`, the constraint stored in `trajopt` is different from the original `PositionConstraint` (it becomes a `Constraint`). Updating the coefficients of the original `PositionConstraint` can't influence the corresponding constraint inside `trajopt`. The conversion from `PositionConstraint` to `Constraint` upon adding it to `trajopt` seems to isolate the `trajopt` constraint from future changes to the original `PositionConstraint` object.

Comment: You're right, this Q is about `KinematicTrajectoryOptimization` and the other Q was about `InverseKinematics`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right.  The `PathConstraint` in use here [makes a copy](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/v1.21.0/planning/trajectory_optimization/kinematic_trajectory_optimization.cc#L47-L48) of the bounds of the wrapped `Constraint`, so any further updates to the wrapped constraint's bounds will be ignored.

If this is in Python, possibly you can figure out a way to identify the `PathConstraint` in the list of `trajopt.get_mutable_prog().generic_constraints()` and call `set_bounds` on that object.

Comment: I tried to call `prog.generic_constraints()[0].set_bounds()` but it has no attribute 'set_bounds' since it is a `pydrake.solvers.BindingConstraint` object. By printing `prog.generic_constraints()[0]` I get `PathConstraint with 28 decision variables control_point(0,16) .....`. It seems that `PathConstraint` does not have public APIs even in C++.

Comment: `prog.generic_constraints()[0].evaluator()` is a `pydrake.solvers.Constraint` object. By using `upper_bound()` and `lower_bound()` I can see the bounds are same with the bounds of `PositionConstraint`. However, it seems there is no way to update bounds of a `pydrake.solvers.Constraint` object.

Comment: I see now.  Those functions are not bound in pydrake.  I think the bottom line is that updating is not possible in current Drake v1.21.  You'll need to recreate the program from scratch.